# How to create Multi Dimensional Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array, printing, key

how to make a Multidimensional Dictionary with multiple keys and value and how to print its keys and values?

from this format:

```
main_dictionary= { Mainkey: {keyA: value
                             keyB: value
                             keyC: value
                 }}
```

I tried to do it but it gives me an error in the manufacturer. here is my code

```
car_dict[manufacturer] [type]= [( sedan, hatchback, sports)]
```

Here is my error:

```
File "E:/Programming Study/testupdate.py", line 19, in campany
car_dict[manufacturer] [type]= [( sedan, hatchback, sports)]
KeyError: 'Nissan'
```

And my printing code is:

```
            for manufacuted_by, type,sedan,hatchback, sports in cabuyao_dict[bgy]:
                print("Manufacturer Name:", manufacuted_by)
                print('-' * 120)
                print("Car type:", type)
                print("Sedan:", sedan)
                print("Hatchback:", hatchback)
                print("Sports:", sports)
```

Thank you! I'm new in Python.

Comment: If you code is raising "an error", please include the actual error and the code that provided that error. We cannot be sure of what actual error you're getting, so we can't  really help you without guessing what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a slight misunderstanding of how a `dict` works, and how to "call back" the values inside of it.

Let's make two examples for how to create your data-structure:

```
car_dict = {}
car_dict["Nissan"] = {"types": ["sedan", "hatchback", "sports"]}
print(car_dict) #  Output: {'Nissan': {'types': ['sedan', 'hatchback', 'sports']}}

from collections import defaultdict
car_dict2 = defaultdict(dict)
car_dict2["Nissan"]["types"] = ["sedan", "hatchback", "sports"]
print(car_dict2) # Output: defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Nissan': {'types': ['sedan', 'hatchback', 'sports']}})
```

In both examples above, I first create a dictionary, and then on the row after I add the values I want it to contain. In the first example, I give `car_dict` the `key` `"Nissan"` and set it's values to a new dictionary containing some values.

In the second example I use `defaultdict(dict)` which basically has the logic of "if i am not given a `value` for `key` then use the factory (`dict`) to create a `value` for it.

Can you see the difference of how to initiate the values inside of both of the different methods?

When you called `car_dict[manufacturer][type]` in your code, you hadn't yet initiated `car_dict["Nissan"] = value`, so when you tried to retrieve it, `car_dict` returned a `KeyError`.

As for printing out the values, you can do something like this:

```
for key in car_dict:
    manufacturer = key
    car_types = car_dict[key]["types"]
    print(f"The manufacturer '{manufacturer}' has the following types:")
    for t in car_types:
        print(t)
```

Output:

```
The manufacturer 'Nissan' has the following types:
sedan
hatchback
sports
```

When you loop through a `dict`, you are looping through *only* the keys that are contained in it by default. That means that we have to retrieve the values of `key` inside of the loop itself to be able to `print` them correctly.

---

Also as a side note: You should try to avoid using Built-in's names such as `type` as variable names, because you then overwrite that functions namespace, and you can have some problems in the future when you have to do comparisons of types of variables.